# Temporarily store relevant public and private keys (after a successful key-exchange) in a WebAPI scenario

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security

I have written an API to implement the Diffie Hellman key exchange and now wanted to store my "server" private/public keys in a secure and expirable way so that I can access them on the subsequent api calls.

The idea is to have the client initiate the exchange of the keys, then have the client send me an encrypted message based on his privatekey that I can decrypt on the server because I have my related privateKey.

My problem is **where to store securely the list of various public/private server keys** in a way that I could reuse it when referenced at later stage.

My initial idea would be to have some sort of static list that contains

> KeyID            (Guid - autogenerated)
>   Expiration Date   (DateTime - now + 20 seconds)
>   ServerPublicKey  (byte[] - resulted  from successful key exchange)
>   ServerPrivateKey (byte[] - resulted  from successful key exchange)

On completion of the KeyExchange I could return a KeyID to the client caller and then on subsequent API calls, he should pass an encrypted message using his clientPrivate key. By also passing me the KeyID, I could quickly identify what is the related serverPrivateKey and Decrypt the message.

Is this the right and most secure approach?